# Getting an error 'String' does not contain a definition for 'Order' and no accessible extension method...' when configuring a relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to configure a one-to-many relationship between my two entities `Order` and `Item`. However, I am getting this error:

> Error CS1061: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Orders' and no accessible extension method 'Orders' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This is the code for my `DbContext`:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using OrderEase.Models;

namespace OrderEase.Data
{
    public class OrderDbContext:DbContext
    {
        public OrderDbContext(DbContextOptions<OrderDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        //Configure Relationships
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
                        .HasOne(ur => ur.Items)
                        .WithMany(u => u.Order)
                        .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.OrderID)
                        .IsRequired();

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

A navigation property has been added in the `Item` class as shown here:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace OrderEase.Models
{
    public class Item
    {
        [Key]
        public int ItemID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Item name is required")]
        [Display(Name = "Item Name")]
        public string ItemName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Item price is required")]
        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        [Display(Name = "Price")]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Quantity in stock is required")]
        [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Quantity must be non-negative")]
        public int QuantityInStock { get; set; }

        //One-to-Many Relationship with Order

        public int OrderID { get; set; }   // foreign key referencing order
        public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is my `Order` model class:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal;
using OrderEase.Data;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace OrderEase.Models
{
    public class Order
    {
        [Key]
        public int? OrderID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string  Item { get; set; }

        [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Quantity must be greater than 0.")]
        public int Quantity { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Display(Name = "Order Date")]
        public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Display(Name = "Delivery Date")]
        public DateTime DeliveryDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Supplier { get; set; }
        public OrderStatus OrderStatus { get; set; }

        // Relationship 
        public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Please kindly advise when I went wrong.

I checked my name spaces too. Everything seems fine.

[OrderDbContext code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiDD9.png)

Comment: Can you add your `Order` model?

Comment: Please check the post now. I've added the Order model there.

Comment: What you have now is incorrect: `HasOne(ur => ur.Items)` doesn't work with a collection `Items`. I'd suggest you look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/one-to-many).

Answer (score 1):

Your **OnModelCreating** method is wrong (HasOne... WithMany...), and cannot be compiled.

You should use that of YSFKBDY (correcting the line .HasForeignKey...) so:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{    
    modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
        .HasMany(ur => ur.Items)
        .WithOne(u => u.Order)
        .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.OrderID)
        .IsRequired();

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

After that, all is ok, and compiling will be fine too.

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you an example to follow:

```
public class Order
{
    //...Other properties
    
    public string  Item { get; set; } //Remove this line
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; } //Remove this line
    public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; } //Add this row to your Order model
}

public class Item
{
    //...Other properties
    
    public int OrderId { get; set; } //Add this line
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; } //Add this line
    public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; } //Remove this line
}
```

And on your model creating, change your code like this:

```
namespace OrderEase.Data
{
    public class OrderDbContext:DbContext
    {
        public OrderDbContext(DbContextOptions<OrderDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        //Configure Relationships
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
            .HasMany(ur => ur.Items)
            .WithOne(u => u.Order)
            .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.OrderId)
            .IsRequired();

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried the above but the Order remains underlined.

Comment: Did you update your models as above? Can you please compare your code?

Comment: The error message is now indicating that '
 'ICollection<Item>' does not contain a definition for 'Order' and no accessible extension method 'Order' accepting a first argument of type 'ICollection<Item>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)' in the DbContext

Comment: You should import ICollection. Add this line to your Order model's top: using System.Collections.Generic;

Comment: Yes, I updated the code as per your suggestion.

Comment: Add this top of your code Order model: using System.Collections.Generic;

Comment: The compiler is now indicating that the directive is unnecessary

Comment: You are missing something, but I don't know what it is. Sorry :/ Maybe you can edit your question with your updated code?

Comment: Thank you so much YSFKBDY for the correction above. It worked